# PHP result set display format

Tags: php, sql

Hi i have a query which will result three rows of results at present. I need to show them in some way but i am not able to show like that. Can you give me some idea how i need to approach it.

I will have all the result set in an array from database.

```
1. client name |RO NO |  channel  
2. a           | abc  |   x
3. a           | abc  |   y
4. a           | abc  |   z
```

Result set look like above but i need to display it like below in a table

```
1. client      a
2. RO         abc  
3. Channel     x,y,z
```

I don't want repeat which are common in each row. How should i do it. Can any one give me idea how to proceed...

Comment: Actually i am using codeiginiter framework so i will result in an array from database using model and i will forward that array to view file from controller........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select `client name` as `client`, `RO NO` as `RO`, group_concat(channel) as `Channel`
from table_name
group by `client`
```

Comment: very useful but suppose if channels are also repeat like x,x,y if i concatenate using above query it will give x,x,y but i need x,y...........how should i get like that

Comment: select `client name` as `client`, `RO NO` as `RO`, group_concat(channel) as `Channel`, `channel`
from table_name
group by `client`, `channel` @venkatabandla this should work in that situation. Query was not formatted well by editor, sorry.

Comment: it will work if you changed to  group_concat(distinct channel).......i tested it now thanks for idea......

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

Use the result as array key:

```
$arr[$result] = true;
echo implode(',', array_keys($arr));
```

## MySQL

Group concat with distinct:

```
select group_concat(distinct ...) from ...;
```